# Можно ли считать данную ситуацию неопределенным поведением?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%p\n", NULL);
}
```

В стандарте говорится, что

> **7.19 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`**
>
> 3. The macros are
>
>    ```
>    NULL
>    ```
>
>    which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant;

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 3. An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

> **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> 8. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
>    <…>
>
>    **`p`** The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is
>      converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>      manner.
>
>    <…>
> 9. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Получается, что если реализация определяет тип `NULL` как `void *`, то приведенный выше код абсолютно валиден. Если же тип `NULL` в конкретной реализации не будет являться указателем на `void`, то в следствии 7.21.6.1/9 получится UB.

Так вот меня интересует, как в целом называются такие ситуации, когда наличие или отсутствие в коде неопределенного поведения зависит от реализации. Правильно ли говорить, что приведенный выше код содержит UB?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102440/discussion-on-question-by-eanmos------).

Comment: Из [man printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) -- *`"The void * pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal (as if by %#x or %#lx)"`. Т.е. любая **разумная реализация** `printf` напечатает шестнадцатеричное представление этого аргумента, рассматриваемого как указатель (разыменовывать его (обращаться по нему в память) `printf` не будет).

Comment: @eanmos, imho в более интересной формулировке (не уверен, что прокатит на SO) ваш вопрос звучал бы так -- "Каким должен быть ABI, чтобы  в соответствии с пунктами стандартов ...  `printf("%p", 0)` не вызывал UB?"

Comment: @avp, так тут же дело не в ABI. `printf("%p", 0)` это в любом случае UB из-за несоответствия типа аргумента (`0`, `int`) и соответствующего спецификатора (`%p`, `void *`).

Comment: @eanmos, отчего же? Как раз все дело в правильном ABI. Попробуйте `printf(argv[1], 0, '\n');` и запустив `./a.out 'Null: %p %c'` вы увидите тот же вывод, что и для `printf("Null: %p \n", NULL);` / Тут все дело в головах людей, которые придумали *разумные правила* передачи переменного числа аргументов в функцию (по крайней мере для конкретной системы GNU + x86-64). / Пример с `argv[1]` для того, чтобы никто не ссылался на компайлер, котрый видит строку форматов

Comment: @avp, я не совсем понимаю, как ABI влияет на наличие или отсутствие в коде UB.

Comment: @eanmos, реально имеет смысл говорить о UB (Undefined Behavior) применительно к каждой системе программирования отдельно (т.е. говорить о конкретном ABI и компиляторе), а не  обобщать пункты  стандарта.

Comment: @avp, наличие или отсутствие UB в коде не зависит от компилятора или ABI. Это же прописано в стандарте. Код, который содержит UB, будет содержать UB в независимости от реализации.

Comment: @eanmos, видимо у нас разные взгляды на UB и ценность стандартов. Мне ближе приземленная позиция -- *`"... вам шашечки или ехать надо? ..."`*

Comment: @avp, пожалуй, да :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Язык С, по определению, допускает только два варианта [*null pointer constant*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3):

1. Целочисленное константное выражение со значением `0`.
2. Целочисленное константное выражение со значением `0`, приведенное к типу `void *`.

Все. Больше вариантов нет.

`NULL` в первую очередь обязан быть *null pointer constant*, то есть полностью подчиняться вышеприведенному определению *null pointer constant*. Определение `NULL`, как "*implementation-defined* null pointer constant" в данном случае означат лишь свободу выбора варианта в рамках вышеприведенного определения. Никакие другие варианты определения `NULL` не допускаются.

Поэтому `NULL` всегда, без вариантов, является "нулевым". Разумеется, объектное представление указателя типа `void *`, проинициализированного `NULL`, может быть ненулевым, но к самому `NULL` это не имеет никакого отношения. `NULL` не является lvalue и не имеет объектного представления.

Код

```
printf("%p\n", NULL);
```

в общем случае имеет неопределенное поведение, если `NULL` окажется определенным по варианту 1.

Вот так в целом и называются такие ситуации. "Код в общем случае имеет неопределенное поведение". "Поведение зависит от implementation-defined факторов и может быть неопределенным". Принципиальной разницы с каким-нибудь

```
int i = 1 << 30;
++i;
```

тут нет. Тут тоже "поведение зависит от implementation-defined факторов и может быть неопределенным".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102444/discussion-on-answer-by-ant-------).